# how get data to object when call api use https.request in nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

i try get data to variable 'results' when call an api another but unidentified

```
let results;
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {

      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (body) => {
         results = JSON.parse(body).payUrl;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
         console.log('No more data in response.');
     });
});
console.log(results);
```

`results = unidentified`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `https.request(options,(res)=>{})` `res` is a stream and will emit data in chunk on event 'data'. So you won't get complete data in one go. You change code something as bellow:

```
  let results;
  let url;
  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
          res.setEncoding('utf8');
          let body="";
          res.on('data', (chunk) => {
           body = body+chunk   // aggregate data
          })
          res.on('end', () => {
           // once data is completly fetched do JSON.parse();
            console.log('No more data in response.')
            results = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(results)
            url =  results.url
            console.log(url);
         })

      });
      req.on('error', (e) => {
         // listen for error 
          console.log(e.message);
       });
```

Also,`https.request(options,(res)=>{})` is async call so `console.log(results)` in your code will be executed even before api calls complete.

Comment: i user graphql and i want show data on graphql 'http://localhost:3000/graphql'  so that i need custom data show graphql